# How to loop a telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

#I need to write a telegram bot on python. After entering the command, he must translate the words and enter them into the dictionary. But he only translates one word. How to make a bot able to translate an infinite number of words. Help please. I'm asking a question here for the first time, so I'm sorry if something is wrong.

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types
from translate import Translator

TOKEN = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

translator = Translator(from_lang='ru', to_lang='en')
slova = {}

@bot.message_handler(commands = 'learn')
def welcome(message):
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Write me words')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, transl)
        

def transl(message):
        perevod = translator.translate(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, perevod)
        slova[message.text] = perevod


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with a telegram bot and translating before so i'm not sure if there is already a built-in function for this. But you could try something like this.

```
sentence = "This is a sentence!"
translated_sentence = ""

for word in sentence.split():
    translated_sentence += translator.translate(word)
```